# If I'm reviewing late answers, please don't remind me repeatedly to vote on questions

Tags: feature-request, review, late-answers

This request is based on the new review queue, but if the old review page sticks around for a while, it's just as problematic there.

I understand the fact that the system will likely remind me if I haven't voted on questions for a while (I don't completely agree with it, but that is not the focus of this question).  If I'm in the Late Answers queue, it's just a fact of life that I'm going to be potentially voting on at least some of the answers for a while.

I could tolerate a reminder or two, maybe every 10 votes or so, but after nearly every vote I get the "You haven't voted on questions for a while" popup.  I haven't let the message linger long enough to see if it dissolves on its own, but regardless, it's intrusive.

Please consider limiting or eliminating the reminder to vote on questions when one is reviewing answers.